# How to fix garbled text with using ReadFile?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I have a Win32 application that I'm making.
Use "ReadFile" to retrieve a text file that is written in Unicode. 
To be printed in the EditBox.

```
const TCHAR FILE_DIRECTORY[] = TEXT("data/");
const TCHAR FILE_LIST[][MAX_LOADSTRING] = { 
    TEXT("fputs_fgets.h"), TEXT("fprintf_fscanf.h"), 
    TEXT("fprintfs_fscanfs.h"), TEXT("fread_fwrite.h"), TEXT("freads_fwrite.h") };
const int FILE_NAME_LENGTH = _tcslen(FILE_LIST[idx]);
const int FILE_DIRECTORY_LENGTH = _tcslen(FILE_DIRECTORY);

TCHAR* filePath = (TCHAR*)calloc(FILE_NAME_LENGTH + FILE_DIRECTORY_LENGTH + 1, sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy_s(filePath, FILE_DIRECTORY_LENGTH + 1, FILE_DIRECTORY);
_tcscat_s(filePath, FILE_NAME_LENGTH + FILE_DIRECTORY_LENGTH + 1, FILE_LIST[idx]);

HANDLE file = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(file, NULL);
DWORD dwRead;

if (editText != NULL)
    free(editText);
editText = (TCHAR*)calloc(1, fileSize + 1);
ReadFile(file, editText, fileSize, &dwRead, NULL);
CloseHandle(file);
free(filePath);
```

However, there are some strange characters on the back of the output.

```
        printf("y좌표(정수): %d\n", point.y);
    }

    fclose(file);
}ﴀ﷽ý
```

How can i fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: *"Unicode"* is not a character encoding. What character encoding does the textfile use, and what character encoding does your program use? Do keep in mind, that `ReadFile` does not zero-terminate the contents read.

Comment: How do you write the output part? You have only shown the read part here... and I suspect the error to lie there

Comment: @IInspectable: In the WinAPI world, Unicode should be read as UTF-16. The use of TCHAR suggests that  the file is a Windows Unicode (read UTF-16 encoded) file. UTF-8 is far from common on Windows...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: A textfile is not a concept of the Windows API. You have to know its encoding. Blindly interpreting it as UTF-16 isn't going to end well. And that's assuming, that the OP is compiling for Unicode. I cannot see that from the question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The text file written here is a file saved by the general Notepad as an Unicode type.

Comment: @IInspectable: *a text file that is written in Unicode* looks clear to me... It is usualy a discutable design because non Microsoft tools often do not like UTF16 text files, but notepad easily edits them .

Comment: Why are you using TCHAR?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there anything wrong with using TCHAR?
i'm using TCHAR because i heard that it is good to use it. i'm not sure because i'm still a beginner. ㅠㅠ

Comment: No, it's not a good idea. Its purpose is to support single source code base for Windows 9x which didn't support Unicode and Windows NT which does. It hasn't been sensible to use TCHAR for over ten years now.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: The sentence you quoted (which is apparently clear to you) doesn't make any sense whatsoever. You cannot write in Unicode. You write files using one of the Unicode character encodings. We have no information whatsoever, what encoding the source file is in. Nor do we know the target encoding the OP is using. If all of that is clear to you, then by all means, do drop an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file is UTF-16 and you are compiling with `_UNICODE` defined (assumptions justified by the fact that the rest of your text is read correctly), in this line:

```
editText = (TCHAR*)calloc(1, fileSize + 1);
```

you should actually do `fileSize + sizeof(TCHAR)` if you want to exploit the zeroing that `calloc` does to get a NUL-terminated string. As it is now, you have a wide string whose last character has only the low byte to zero, so the rest of your code goes on reading garbage until it happens to find two solid bytes of zero (adequately aligned).

Mind you, I'm extremely dubious about this code in general - if you use `TCHAR` it means you want to compile both in ANSI (`TCHAR == char`) and in Unicode (`TCHAR ==wchar_t`), having this change how you interpret the bytes of external files is a disputable idea.